# Run Cleanup Before Stopping SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have a SQL Server Agent Job which calls a SSIS package. If the user forcefully stops the job, then the SSIS package will also stop execution.

Is it possible to intercept this stop request and run a SQL script to perform any required operations (such as cleanup or custom logging)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in sql server, but what you can do is create another recurring sql job to check if there is some cleanup needs to be performed, if yes then run the cleanup script else stop the job.

schedule the cleanup job based on your original job schedule.